# How to call maven-antrun-plugin target without attach execution to a maven phase ?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I use maven-antrun-plugin for init config files for my project. But i need to init config files just once, when i first start to init my dev environment, not each time i launch jetty:run.

If I attach phase to process-resouces for example, each time I launch jetty, my config files are reseted.

So i configured antrun like this :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <target name="init_config_files">
                <!-- init files -->
            </target>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If I launch mvn antrun:run, it just return me this error : "[INFO] No ant target defined - SKIPPED". And it is the same thing, if I specify target : "mvn antrun:run -Dtarget=init_config_files".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                            <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and run this:

```
 mvn antrun:run
```

Answer (score 6):

Best solution I have found so far:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>go-live</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <!-- go live! -->
                            <exec executable="${basedir}/deploy2server.sh" failonerror="true" dir="${basedir}">
                                <arg value="deploy" />
                                <arg value="${deploy.to.server}" />
                                <arg value="${jetty.port.live}" />
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and run this:

```
 mvn antrun:run@go-live
```

This solution avoids the target being run by accident, ie. it does not run just by typing "mvn antrun:run" and it also does not run during regular maven runs. I'm using this for qa auto-deployment in my jenkins instance after all modules incl integration done against the final distribution package have been successfully executed.

Comment: Very good solution. With this method you can have several executions and you can select one of them.

Comment: THE best answer ever!  With your help I now can run separate executions :D Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem and finally figured it out: If you want to run the ant tasks only once, you can set the plugin up like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <target name="init_config_files">
            <!-- init files -->
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and use `mvn antrun:run` to execute it. That way, the ant stuff is not bound to any phase.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run some part of build on special conditions (e.g. once), you can put those parts into a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and then invoke Maven specifying profile name, e.g. `mvn -p init_config_files package`

Comment: I already use this solution for another plugin, I was just blocked on my idea : "why antrun absolutely want to be attach to a phase? " :)
Thx